# push forward of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

I just want to check that my definition of the push forward of a vector field is correct. So I have a vector field $X$ on $M$ and a diffeomorphism $\phi:M\to N$.

Then $\phi_*X$ is defined as follows

$$(\phi_*X)(x)(f) = (\phi_{*\phi^{-1}(x)}X_{\phi^{-1}(x)})(f) = X_{\phi^{-1}(x)}(f\circ\phi)$$

where $x\in N$ and $f\in C^{\infty}(N)$

Comment: I don't understand the middle term in that equality, because I don't know what $X_\star$ means. The last one, however, looks OK.

Comment: my bad. It should be $X_{\phi^{-1}(x)}$

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [push forward of vector field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319768/push-forward-of-vector-field)